# Is there a way to use the existing variables in a random array method in another method?

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods

I want to use the variables generated in my `randomRainMonth()` method to be used for calculation in another method `totalRain()`. But by using `double[] totalsum = randomRainMonth(list);` in my `totalRain()` it would just generate a new set of random variables as it would invoke the method again. Can anyone help?

```
public class RainFall{

  public static void main (String[] args){

    double [] monthRain = new double[12];
    String[] monthName = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    randomRainMonth(monthRain);
    System.out.println("-------");
    totalRain(monthRain, monthName);
//    printMonths(monthName);
  }

  public static String[] printMonths(String list[]){     
    String[] pM = new String[list.length];  
    for (int i = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
        //System.out.println(list[i]);
      }
    return pM;
  }

    public static double[] randomRainMonth(double list[]){
      double[] rdMonth = new double[list.length];

      for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        rdMonth[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        //System.out.println(rdMonth[i]);
      }
      return rdMonth;
  }

    public static double[] totalRain(double list[], String list2 []){

      String[] mnth = printMonths(list2);
      double[] totalsum = randomRainMonth(list);

      double sum = 0;
      for( double i : totalsum) {
        sum += i;
      }


      for (int i = 0; i<list2.length; i++) {

      System.out.print(mnth[i] +": ");
      System.out.println(totalsum[i]);
      }
      System.out.println("Total: ");
      System.out.println(sum);

      return totalsum;

    }
}
```

[SOLVED]
Final code:

```
public class RainFall{

  public static void main (String[] args){


    double[] monthRain = randomRainMonth();
    String[] monthName = printMonths();
//    randomRainMonth();
    System.out.println("-------");
    totalRain(monthRain, monthName);
//    printMonths(monthName);
    avgRainMonthly(monthRain);
  }

  public static String[] printMonths(){     
    String[] monthName = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};  
    for (int i = 0; i<12; i++) {
        //System.out.println(monthName[i]);
      }
    return monthName;
  }

 public static double[] randomRainMonth(){

      double [] monthRain = new double[12];
      for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        monthRain[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        //System.out.println(monthRain[i]);
      }
      return monthRain;
  }

    public static double[] totalRain(double list[], String list2 []){

      String[] mnth = list2;
      double[] totalsum = list;

      double sum = 0;
      for( double i : totalsum) {
        sum += i;
      }


      for (int i = 0; i<12; i++) {

      System.out.print(mnth[i] +": ");
      System.out.println(totalsum[i]);
      }
      System.out.println("Total: ");
      System.out.println(sum);

      return totalsum;

    }

    public static double[] avgRainMonthly(double list []){

      double[] average = list;

      double avg = 0;
      double finAvg = 0;
      for( double a : average) {
        avg = avg + a;
        finAvg = avg / 12;
      }
      System.out.println(finAvg);
      return average;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call the methods again in `totalRain`, you have `list1` and `list2` - what do you actually want in `totalRain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create `double [] monthRain = new double[12];` ahead of the `randomRainMonth(monthRain);` method call, because the actual array object needs to be created and returned by the method `randomRainMonth`.

Rather, you need to declare a `double[]` array `monthRain` in your `main` and then collect the result returned by the `randomRainMonth(monthRain)` as below:

```
//declare the double array
double[] monthRain = randomRainMonth();
```

`randomRainMonth()` method changed as below:

```
public static double[] randomRainMonth(){
      //this method should be responsible to create the double array object 
      //and then return it to the caller after populating with elements
      double [] monthRain = new double[12];

      for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        rdMonth[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
        //System.out.println(rdMonth[i]);
      }
      return monthRain;
  }
```

Now, you can pass the collected array (returned by `randomRainMonth`) to the next method as below (which u are already doing):

```
totalRain(monthRain, monthName);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But the code for the `randomRainMonth()` method you gave me is not quite right. I've posted my final code. Again thanks so much for your help

Comment: great that it is working, you are talking about the variable monthRain, corrected above